# Armature selection using a eyedropper

Tags: python, add-on, properties

I created an addon that uses an eyedropper to select an armature.
The type retrieved is determined by how the object is selected.
Using an eyedropper makes it an "Object", and using a list makes it an "Armature".
Please point out my mistake.
Or is this by design?

Eyedropper

```
type: <class 'bpy_types.Object'>
```

[image]

List

```
type: <class 'bpy_types.Armature'>
```

[image]

My program

```
import bpy
from bpy.types import Panel,Operator

bl_info = {
    "name": "sample",
    "author": "Kageji",
    "version": (0, 0, 0),
    "blender": (2, 83, 0),
    "location": "3D View > Sidebar",
    "description": "",
    "warning": "",
    "support": "TESTING",
    "wiki_url": "",
    "tracker_url": "",
    "category": "Object",
}

class Sample_Panel(Panel):
    bl_label = "sample"
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"
    bl_region_type = "UI"
    bl_category = "sample"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        scene = context.scene
        layout.prop_search(scene, "targetArmature", bpy.data, "armatures", text="", icon="ARMATURE_DATA")
        layout.operator(Sample_Operator.bl_idname, text="Button")


class Sample_Operator(Operator):
    bl_idname = "sampleoperator.operator"
    bl_label = "sampleoperator"

    def execute(self, context):
        obj = context.scene.targetArmature
        self.report({'INFO'}, "type: {} Object: {}".format(str(type(obj)), str(obj)))
        return {"FINISHED"}


classes = [Sample_Panel, Sample_Operator]


def register():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.register_class(cls)
    bpy.types.Scene.targetArmature = bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=bpy.types.Object)
    print("rename mixamorig bone name is active")


def unregister():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.unregister_class(cls)
        del bpy.types.Scene.targetArmature
    print("rename mixamorig bone name is inactive")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: Hi. You get two different types because your script requests two different types. It works as designed ;-) In line 27 the *prop_search* looks for *"armatures"*, while in line 47 the *targetArmature* is a *PointerProperty* of *bpy.types.Object*. If you want to have objects then change line 27 to *"objects"*, for armatures change line 47 to *bpy.types.Armature*.

Comment: I see. Understood.
My understanding of blenders has deepened.
Thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Armature selection using a eyedropper](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/310224/armature-selection-using-a-eyedropper?noredirect=1#comment537430_310224)

> Hi. You get two different types because your script requests two different types. It works as designed ;-) In line 27 the prop_search looks for "armatures", while in line 47 the targetArmature is a PointerProperty of `bpy.types.Object`. If you want to have objects then change line 27 to "objects", for armatures change line 47 to `bpy.types.Armature`.

I have made some changes based on this comment.
Changed `bpy.props.PointerProperty` type to `bpy.types.Amature`.

> line 47
> `bpy.types.Scene.targetArmature = bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=bpy.types.Object)`
> `bpy.types.Scene.targetArmature = bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=bpy.types.Armature)`